# Binding a String to a richtextbox

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a datagrid populated with "notes"  and when a note is clicked I want the richtextbox to show the note.comments. But the Bindings isn't working.

```
public NoteDTO SelectedNote {get; set;}
public string stringNotes {get; set;}

public void OpenNote()
{
    stringNotes = SelectedNote.Comments;
}



<DataGrid x:Name="NoteGrid" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [Action OpenNote()]" ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNote}"


<toolkit:RichTextBox Text="{Binding stringNotes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

If I may get help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you're binding to a property that has no concept of change notifications; you're not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  That being said, why not just bind the RichTextBox directly to the property off of `NoteDTO`:

```
<toolkit:RichTextBox Text="{Binding SelectedNote.Comments, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The other option is to manually copy the comments between `SelectedNote` and `stringNotes`, then implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but this isn't ideal unless you want to have an intermediate property before propagating them to the `NoteDTO` object.

EDIT:

I noticed that your `SelectedNote` property will never notify the UI that it has changed, which will prevent bindings from working.  Try something like the following:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string selectedNote;
    public string SelectedNote
    {
        get { return this.selectedNote; }
        set
        {
            if (this.selectedNote == value)
                return;

            this.selectedNote = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedNote");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method makes total sense. I changed that to SelectedNote.Comments and it still doesn't Populate.

Comment: @user3276954 See my latest edit, in all my talk of implementing that interface I glossed right over that your property needed to implement it.

Comment: Great answer, it actually populates my richtextbox. But now it's appearing as the NoteDTO rather than the text. I tried `<toolkit:RichTextBox Text="{Binding SelectedNote.Comments, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ` also