# Textbox Values Not Saving to Database

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm currently doing a simple address binding and saving to Database, But when I click my save button, it does save but the textbox information is not saved. It just makes another address row full of nulls. I believe it has to do with the get;set; for the binded values. If anyone Could help me figure out why the Textbox values don't save please and thank you.

Xaml side:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Line1"  Text="{Binding SelectedAddress.Line1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="City" Text="{Binding SelectedAddress.City, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedAddress.PostalCode, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

MVVM side:

```
public Address NewAddress { get; set; }
public string Line1 { get { return _address.Line1; } set { _address.Line1 = value; } }
public string City { get { return _address.City; } set { _address.City = value; } }
public string PostalCode{ get { return _address.PostalCode; } set { _address.PostalCode = value; } }
```

I've also Initiated:

```
public AddressViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
{
.....
_address = new Address(); 
}
```

Button action:

```
public void AddNewAddress()
{
    SelectedAddress = new Address();
    SelectedAddress.Line1 = _address.Line1;
    SelectedAddress.PostalCode = _address.PostalCode;
    SelectedAddress.City = _address.City;
    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAddress");
    using (var ctx = DB.Get())
        {
            ctx.Addresses.Add(SelectedAddress);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

I also Implemented OnPropertyChange from the previous post to "Notify"
[Binding a String to a richtextbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237375/binding-a-string-to-a-richtextbox)

Comment: Have you tried profiling the generated db query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controls bind to `SelectedAddress` yet `AddNewAddress()` effectively discards anything stored there and creates a new Address object with values from "somewhere". Since the `_address` field doesn't bind to anything, it will probably contain nulls.

The following code should work and save the values you have entered in the controls:

```
public void AddNewAddress()
{
    using (var ctx = DB.Get())
    {
        ctx.Addresses.Add(SelectedAddress);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAddress");
}
```

Raising `OnPropertyChanged` is useful only if Address contains some auto-generated fields, eg an ID field that is set by the database. Otherwise, you can omit it entirely.

Comment: hello @panagiotis kanavos I wanted to build ontop of this. So it currently gives me error "SelectedAddress" cannot be null, so i Initialized `SelectedAddress = new SelectedAddress()` in the public AddressViewModel. That works great, it saves. But now this removes the ability to view The address when selected in the grid. It creates an empty SelectedAddress therefore won't display previous ones. Any ideas on a way around?

Answer (score 0):

Seems some mistakes there:

- As Panagiotis said, there is no value for _address.
- You should bind your context to your view (textboxes). If you're creating SelectedAddress just after button pressed, there is no relationship between data you entered in Textboxes and new SelectedAddress. You actually eliminate it.